# WebBrowser ignores the code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, webbrowser-control

I am trying to use Mibbit irc in my project, and so far is working well, but there is a flaw. Links pasted in the chat upon click are getting opened in Internet explorer, instead of users' default web browser. I tried implementing a simple code, but half of it seems to get ignored.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKGGr.jpg

WebBrowser Component Startup page: http://widget.mibbit.com/?settings=4abcd3a5f0bf25306d4c6d1968e28cb2&server=irc.mibbit.net&channel=%23Mytestchannel12345

Ignore if contains: mibbit.com(the chat widged) & ad4game.com(the stupid banner...)
If contains because it places different banners - thus, different links. As well for the widged, it obviously have several servers that is hosting it on and it redirects to some of them, like widged1.mibbit.com, widged2.mibbit.com, etc.

Open in Default user browser: All, except those 2 above.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub WebBrowser1_Navigating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.Navigating
    Dim navTo As String = e.Url.ToString
    If Not (navTo.ToLower.Contains("mibbit.com") OrElse navTo.ToLower.Contains("ad4game.com") OrElse navTo.ToLower.Contains("about:blank")) Then
        e.Cancel = True
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.Url.ToString())
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Nothing so far worked...

Comment: I'm sure you know that the WebBrowser control is part of .NET, not part of VB.NET?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've updated your code sample:

Add a new function to find out what the path to the default browser is:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub WebBrowser1_Navigating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.Navigating
    Dim navTo As String = e.Url.ToString
    If Not (navTo.ToLower.Contains("mibbit.com") OrElse navTo.ToLower.Contains("ad4game.com") OrElse navTo.ToLower.Contains("about:blank")) Then
        e.Cancel = True
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(GetDefaultBrowserPath, e.Url.ToString())
    End If
End Sub

' get the default folder path from the registry
Public Function GetDefaultBrowserPath() As String
    Dim defaultbrowser As String = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\HTTP\shell\open\command", "", "Not Found")
    Return Split(defaultbrowser, """")(1)
End Function

End Class
```

Comment: I understood what do you mean, but not quite sure how to achieve it, but I will still try to get something out of it.

Here is a test solution so u can get more familiar with the situation. I've roamed around loads of forums throughout google, but nothing similar to this. I honestly have no idea how to make it possible, if it is, at all. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/75261985/Solution.zip

@John Saunders, thank you for taking care of it, I will have a look at that link you gave me.

Comment: Okay, I'm now on a computer where I can test my code, so I've updated the GetDefaultBrowserPath() function. Try this, it works fine for me.

Comment: I tried using your code, but I'm not quite sure how to manage it to work. Could you provide an example if possible? I'm really at the edge of shift+del everything and begin reading about C# :-(

Comment: If you can't figure out how to copy a function into a module, I don't think moving from VB.Net to C# is going to help you. But if you don't know how to use either language, then it probably makes more sense to learn C# as it's a more popular language.

Comment: I did tried copying it, after the try it didn't do anything and I don't know how to modify it. I'm obviously doing something wrong and I can't figure out what myself. About the vb.net, I don't know much of it yet, just enough to do basic, but cool stuff. Looking for help means I'm actually dedicated and looking forward to learn it. I've seen a lot of example codes, and get right away how it works, but this one I simply don't. I'm not quite sure which where needs to be put, and/or modified by what way.

Comment: This is why I asked for example project, so I can have a look how it actually works, and know for future how it needs to be done. Experimenting won't work, I've proven this to myself many times already.